# Best Practice with a central app and several other apps - Modules

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have several web-apps that users can access. Every app is based on Spring MVC and they are separated to each other.

Now, I create a centralized app using Spring Boot to manage access and authorization and then I would like to redirect every user to a specified app.

So, I'm thinking to create a main app and all the other apps become modules of this central app.
What do you think? Is it correct?

Otherwise, the alternative is to keep them as separated app and I can use a link to enter in every sub-app.

Which is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are thinking of Facade or Gateway service where you are thinking to do UAA. And via which you will explain your apps to external world. You are going well towards making your application **micro services suitable**. 
Here if you keep all application separate ( at least separate war for each app )  then you can leverage advantages **of loose coupling , high availability and faster scaling.**

Comment: Ok! I was thinking the same.. Every app has a MySql database, so in this case every app keep its own Db. Is it correct? Then for example, now in every app I have a User class, now where can I move this class? Only inside the central app?

Comment: Keep separate application which manages user management. Keep User class inside that.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this Centralized App? Is it just for centralized Authentication/Authorization. If so, you don't need a centralized app to do that. You can just a create a maven project with security filters and let other apps use this dependency so that any access to any app will go through this filter. Again, I would recommend to implement SSO so that the authentication to all application is handled in the filter and username/pwd for all apps are same and stored in some centralized schema in one of the DB.

Comment: And how can I implements SSO? I mean I'm using the Active directory to get the username and password

Comment: It is up to your organization requirements. If it is for your pet app, just a table with userid, username, pwd, role, applicationname is enough to get started. typically organization uses some centralized repo like Active directory, LDAP for Authentication and Sailpoint for Authorization.